# Is there any way to set background like android:tileMode ="repeat" in windows phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way to set background like android:tileMode ="repeat" in windows phone7? if it,how do? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple answer, Silverlight on the phone does not contain built in support for tiling images.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve or what you're trying to set the backgrond of, there are various possible workarounds. But without more information about your specific scenario it's hard to advise further.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I will be try another way.